# vertical output and horizontal output to console.log

Tags: javascript, console

I'm new to programming and am curious so I thought I'd reach out.

I have tested myself with 2 outputs to the console, one being FizzBuzz and the other being a chessboard.

My question is why does my chessboard naturally (without "\n") print horizontally and FizzBuzz print out vertically even though they both use the same for loops?

Thanks, Luke.

**FizzBuzz**,

```
for(let i= 1; i<= 100; i++){
let message= "";
if(i %3 === 0 && i%5 === 0){
    message= "FizzBuzz"
}else if(i % 3 === 0){
    message = "Fizz";
}else if(i % 5 === 0){
    message = "Buzz"
}
console.log(message || i);
};
```

**Chessboard**

```
let size= 8;
let board= ''; 

for (let x = 0; x < size; x++){
for (let y= 0; y < size; y++){
    if((x+y) %2 == 0){
        board += '#';
    }else{
        board += " ";
    }         
 }
 board += "\n"  
}
console.log(board);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the answer.

(A) The code,

```
console.log("Fizz");
console.log("Buzz");
```

gives output

```
"Fizz"
"Buzz"
```

(B) But,

```
console.log("Fizz " + "Buzz");
```

gives output

```
"Fizz Buzz"
```

What you are doing with the FizzBuzz is similar to case (A) and in chessboard is similar to case (B). You are logging in every iteration of the for loop in case (A), but only once for every row in case (B).

Since you are new to programming, remember that each `console.log("whatever");` logs "whatever" in a new line every time it is run.